# post json data to jhipster server using curl or python

Tags: jhipster

How can I do a post request on jhipster server to create some entity and authenticate all at once?

I tried from python with requests module

`requests.post('http://localhost:8080/api/<somelink>', data=json.dumps(somedataforsomelink), headers=headers, auth=(user, password))`

but jhipster in the log tells me that anonymous user is not allowed to do this request, it's like the arguments auth are not taken into account by spring.

my `<somelink>` is protected in jhipster spring boot with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")

once I comment this line, I can do the post of course without problems.

I tried with curl using the -u argument to provide the credentials but same story, the credentials somehow don't get to jhipster as the logs are telling me anonymousUser not allowed where I am using the user user not anonymousUser.

I tried to do also a requests.post('http://localhost:8080/api/authentication'..)  before and I cannot find a way to use the response from login to carry on with my second request call to be able to create my entity.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of authentication do you use (Session, OAuth or Token)?

Comment: For this use case, I use session

Comment: This is the expected behavior, you should authenticate first then store session cookie so that it is sent on next requests.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a Mule REST connector that calls my JHipster app and I used Token authentication (X-Auth-Token) so my situation is a little different. You can however use the API to perform the operations using the CURL commands on the Swagger page. If you're running the JHipster app local in a terminal, you'll see the HTTP traffic. You can also use something like Wireshark to do the same thing. You need to see exactly what an operational HTTP request looks like. For my situation specifically, I had to add "X-Auth-Token: user:142135444yeryreyeyeyre11323" as a header with every subsequent request.

Work with the Swagger page and checkout working HTTP requests and responses.